# Configuring Netbeans on Linux mint with LAMP

Tags: netbeans, configuration, localhost, lamp, linux-mint

(I'm a new by in configuration) I have istalled apache2, mysql, php and netbeans on my pc. I also have an HTML file and php files.

the localhost is located at .var/www/html/ i suppose because in such directory info.php is displayed.

I have also a start on Documents/www/site1 a web site. Now I need to connect the files in Documents/www/site1 to the localhost directory in order to view the file when i click run of netbeans.

Any idea?

Thanks